# What is the space complexity of this algorithm (n or log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, pseudocode, space-complexity

I have a question regarding the space (memory) complexity of this particular piece of pseudocode:

```
int b(int n, int x) {
   int sol = x;
   if (n>1) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         sol = sol+i;
      }
      for (int k=0; k<3; k++) {
         sol = sol + b(n/3,sol/9);
      }
   }
   return sol;
}
```

The code gets called: `b(n,0)`

My opinion is, that the space complexity progresses linearly, that is `n`, because as the input `n` grows, so does the amount of variable declarations (`sol`).

Whereas a friend of mine insists it must be `log(n)`. I didn't quite get his explanation. But he said something about the second `for` loop and that the three recursive calls happen in sequence.

So, is `n` or `log(n)` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number times function `b` is called is `O(n)`, but space complexity is `O(log(n))`.

Recursive calls in your program cause the execution stack to grow. Every time a recursive call takes place all local variables are pushed to the stack (stack size increases). And when function comes back from recursion the local variables are poped from the stack (stack size decreases).

So what you want to calculate here is the maximum size of execution stack, which is maximum depth of recursion, which is clearly `O(log(n))`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see why the maximum depth of recursion is in `O(log(n))`. Why not for example `O(sqrt(n))`? And if it's in `O(log(n))`, which base does the logarithm have and why?

Comment: You start with a function call for n. Then each time you call b, you divide n by 3, so you have n/3, n/9, n/27..., n/3^d (where d is depth of recurtion). So denominator increases **exponentially** - this is why log number of steps are needed to reach 1 (this is when recurtion stops) from n.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. But doesn't that mean the log base should be 3? Such that `O(log_3(n))`?

Comment: Yes, the base of logarithm is 3, but it dosen't matter for complexity considerations. O(log_3(n)) = O(log_2(n)) = O(log_whatever(n)). In the same way, that O(n) = O(2n) = O(7n).

Comment: But isn't O(n^2) different from O(n^3) or from O(n^4)? Or is this only an exception?

Comment: O(n^2) is different from O(n^3) and from O(n^4). The reason that log base doesn't matter is that (for example) log_2(n) = c * log_3(n), where c is some constant number. You can read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base), how to change base of log.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the complexity is

> O(log 3 base (n) )

Comment: Can you explain why you think that?